# Let $(P,<)$ and $(Q,\prec)$ be order isomorphic. What kind of properties that $P$ and $Q$ have in common by the order isomorphism?

Tags: order-theory

> Let $(P,<)$ and $(Q,\prec)$ be order isomorphic. What kind of properties that $P$ and $Q$ have in common by the order isomorphism?

---

When I do exercises (at basic level) related to order isomorphism, I often encounter such statements as:

1. Since $P$ is dense, and $(P,<)$ and $(Q,\prec)$ are order isomorphic, $Q$ is dense.
2. Since $P$ has no endpoints, and $(P,<)$ and $(Q,\prec)$ are order isomorphic, $Q$ has no endpoints.
3. Since $P$ is complete, and $(P,<)$ and $(Q,\prec)$ are order isomorphic, $Q$ is complete.

These statements are usually in the form: Since $P$ is $.....$, and $(P,<)$ and $(Q,\prec)$ are order isomorphic, $Q$ is $.....$.

---

Immediately, two questions appear in my mind:

1. What kind of properties that we can correctly fill in the blank $.....$ in the statement *Since $P$ is $.....$, and $(P,<)$ and $(Q,\prec)$ are order isomorphic, $Q$ is $.....$*

Of course, this kind of properties must relate to the orderings of $P$ and $Q$. Is it still correct if such properties relate to other things besides the orderings. I can not figure out how to describe such kind of properties formally.

2. Is it possible to prove statement $1,2,3$ and similar ones in a general way, rather than prove one by one?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The general rule is: any property which can be expressed using only $<$ and reference to elements of $P$ (so something like "is a dense subset of real numbers" won't cut) will be preserved under isomorphism. You can check this for all of your examples, e.g. "$(P,<)$ is dense" means "for any elements $x,y$ of $P$, if $x<y$, there is element of $P$ such that $x<z<y$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All "order properties", i.e. first order set theory logical formulas that only use $< (\le)$ and set theoretic notions and are quantified over the ordered set and its subsets.

The order $P$ is dense can be formulated as $$\forall x,y \in P: (x < y) \to (\exists z \in P: x < y \land y < z)$$

$P$ has no endpoints:

$$\forall x \in P: \exists a,b \in P: (a < x) \land (x < b)$$

etc. Any order isomorphism must then preserve the truth of such formulas. One could attempt to show this by induction on the complexity of the formula perhaps.